# Why is my console not displaying unmount error in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a mern course. As the guy fetches movie data from backend to react app. But when he logout from homepage, his console showed many error. While mine shows none. What can be the reason to it? As it will cause me huge trouble in future if my console doesn't show such errors. The errors are of memory leaks as he didn't use cleanup function for fetchMovies() function.

[image of his console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cpCt.png)

```
function TopRatedMovies() {
  const { updateNotification } = useNotification();
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const fetchMovies = async () => {
    const { movies, error } = await getTopRatedMovies();
    if (error) return updateNotification("error", error);
    setMovies([...movies]);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);
  return <MovieList movies={movies} title="Viewers Choice (Movies)" />;
}
```

```
export const getTopRatedMovies = async (type) => {
  try {
    let endpoint = "/movie/top-rated";
    if (type) endpoint = endpoint + "?type=" + type;
    const { data } = await client(endpoint);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    const { response } = error;
    return { error: response?.data.msg };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap `fetchMovies` by `useCallback` and add dependency`fetchMovies` for `useEffect` :

```
function TopRatedMovies() {
  const { updateNotification } = useNotification();
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  const fetchMovies = useCallback(async () => {
    const { movies, error } = await getTopRatedMovies();
    if (error) return updateNotification("error", error);
    setMovies([...movies]);
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, [fetchMovies]);
  
  return <MovieList movies={movies} title="Viewers Choice (Movies)" />;
}
```

---

If still the error, can you show your `useNotification` hook?